# Why isn't Stripe localising my Payment Element's fields and error messages?

Tags: javascript, localization, stripe-payments, payment

Stripe Elements (i.e. Stripe.js), including the Payment Element, apparently now supports [localisation/internationalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) out of [the box](https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/supported_locales), and the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_without_intent) for the `locale` parameter says it detects the browser's locale by default and changes the messaging to reflect this:

> **locale** *string*
> A locale to display placeholders and error strings in. Default is auto (Stripe detects the locale of the browser).

However, when I change my browser's language to French, for example, neither omitting the locale field nor explicitly specifying it with `locale: "auto"` translates the language to French - I can only force this behaviour by manually specifying `locale: "fr"`, which seems to suggest that Stripe isn't detecting the browser locale correctly.

What's going on here, and how can I get Stripe to detect the browser's locale like the documentation says it's capable of?

Comment: Can you share more details? I tested this in Chrome after changing the browser language to French; in chrome://settings/languages, I moved "French" to the top of the language list.

I omitted locale altogether and the PaymentElement translated to French

Comment: @LauraT Interesting, I did what is presumably the equivalent in Firefox, and it was at least enough for the language of the browser menus to change to French. Maybe this is an issue with Firefox language changing not actually changing the locale. I tried looking into it before I asked the question and didn't find any other mechanism to change the locale, although it's hard to tell for sure right now since r/firefox (along with the rest of Reddit) is private due to the protest.

Comment: Have you tried asking Stripe tech support?

Comment: @Barmar With the state that Stripe support is in right now, and with the 2 other issues I'm chasing up with them, contacting Stripe nowadays is a slow and painstaking last resort when/if all other resources turn up nothing.

Comment: @HashimAziz I didn't know Stripe support is having problems. We migrated away from Stripe last year, and they were always very helpful when I needed them.

Comment: @Barmar I've definitely noticed a rise in response time and a drop in the quality/reliability of support since I first integrated a few years ago. Who did you migrate to?

Comment: @HashimAziz We're using CyberSource now, I think mainly for cost reasons. It was a really PITA integrating them.

Comment: @HashimAziz aha! Yes, looks like Firefox splits language settings in two. Under about:preferences > Language, the dropdown menu you see there is for browser menus. Immediately below the dropdown, you'll see "Choose your preferred language for displaying pages" with a "Choose" button to the right. When clicked, that button opens up "Webpage Language Settings". If you add French here and move it to the top of the language list, you should see the PaymentElement rendered in French.

Comment: @LauraT Great detective work Laura, it's a very confusing way to arrange the options but I've just confirmed it does work. Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll accept, while not a direct answer to the question I'm sure it will help one of the many future devs trying to integrate Stripe while using Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to how Firefox lays out language settings. They split settings in two. Under about:preferences > Language, the dropdown menu you see there is for browser menus. Immediately below the dropdown, you'll see "Choose your preferred language for displaying pages" with a "Choose" button to the right. When clicked, that button opens up "Webpage Language Settings". If you add French here and move it to the top of the language list, you should see the PaymentElement rendered in French.